# I use gnuplot to output png but cannot open the png pictures

Tags: gnuplot

I use gnuplot to out put a png picture. Then the picture has been generate, but I cannot open it. What's the reason? I can open other png pictures on the ubuntu.

```
#! /usr/bin/gnuplot
set terminal emf size 1280,960 font '/usr/common/fonts/simsun.ttc,14'  
set style data histograms
set style fill transparent pattern 1 border
set grid
set title '有/无多AP协作下，AP吞吐量对比'
set output 'BSS吞吐量对比曲线.png'
set xlabel 'BSS'
set ylabel 'AP 吞吐量/Mbps'
#set xtics('BSS1' 0,'BSS2' 1,'BSS3' 2,'BSS4' 3,'BSS5' 4)
set xrange [-1:5]
set yrange [0:7000]
plot 'hewthroughput.txt' using 2:xticlabels(1) title '无多AP协作',\
'hewthroughput.txt' using 3:xticlabels(1) title '有多AP协作',\
'hewthroughput.txt' using ($1-1):($2+200):($2) with labels notitle,\
'hewthroughput.txt' using ($1-0.8):($3+200):($3) with labels notitle
```

Comment: Show us the gnuplot code.

Comment: I have edited this again, and show my code in the image. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I have copy the code here.

Answer (score 2):

`set terminal emf` means you're [creating an EMF file](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node409.html). That you have set the filename to use `.png` doesn't mean that it will magically become a PNG file. If you want to make PNG files with gnuplot, use [`set terminal png`](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node409.html).